# Intuitive explanation of even/odd permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Given a permutation it can be classified as either even or odd depending on whether it is expressible as a product of even or odd number of transpositions. Is there some geometrical or intuitive meaning for this? Secondly what is the significance of classifying permutations as even or odd?

Thanks

Update: I am looking for a motivation for the classification of permutations as even and odd when a student first encounters them. For example rotations in $D_n$ can be used to motivate $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Likewise I was looking for a general motivation for even/odd permutations. At an advanced level there is the motivation that $A_n$ is simple for $n\ge 5$, but is there any motivation for a novice?

Comment: There are many reasons really. First from an algebra point of view you wish to study subgroups of a group in order to tell you things about the group itself. The alternating group $A_n$, consisting of all even permutations, is a subgroup of $S_n$ for any $n$. This subgroup has index $2$ and so is maximal.

Comment: I have turned it into an answer. Although this was just an example. Permutations turns out to be very handy in solving lots of puzzles such as rubiks cube etc. Even/oddness has its uses in most of these.

Answer (score 4):

**Why "Odd" and "Even"?**

The symmetric group $S_n$ maps homomorphically onto the cyclic group of order two $(\{0, 1\}, +_{\operatorname{mod}2})$. By homomorphically, I mean that the map preserves the group structure, in the sense that if we denote the map $f:S_n\rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ then $f(\sigma\tau)=f(\sigma)+_{\operatorname{mod}2}f(\tau)$. Odd permutations map to the non-trivial element $1$ in this map, while even permutations map to the trivial element $0$. This is the reason behind calling them *odd* and *even*, because we have the following operations:

- $odd+odd=even$, and $1+_{\operatorname{mod}2}1=0$.
- $even+odd=odd$, and $0+_{\operatorname{mod}2}1=1$.
- $odd+even=odd$, and $1+_{\operatorname{mod}2}0=1$.
- $even+even=even$, and $0+_{\operatorname{mod}2}0=0$.

Therefore, this homomorphism is mimicking addition of odd and even numbers. The even permutations are the *[kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28algebra%29#Group_homomorphisms)* of this map (homomorphism), and this means that they form a subgroup (or rather, a *normal subgroup*, by the [first isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem)), called the alternating group $A_n$.

**Applications**

For a cool, but, I will admit, slightly advanced application of parity, look up Theorem 11.2.1 of David Joyner's book *Adventures in Group Theory*. The theorem gives necessary and sufficient conditions for a certain kind of 4-tuple to represent an element of the group underlying the Rubik's cube.

Indeed, I would recommend looking up Joyner's book if you want examples of applications. The book is based around applying group theory to puzzles, and mostly these applications use symmetric group arguments. For example, Section 7.4 of the book proves (using the parity of the permutations) that the 15 puzzle has no solution (this is, of course, fretty's answer). I especially like Section 3.4, which explains a practical application of permutation groups to [campanology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campanology).

Comment: Thanks. Another reason for calling them odd/even permutation is the parity of the number of inversions.

Comment: @Shahab Yes, but that is simply because every inversion is mapped to $1$. Can you see why this is?

Comment: Another way to look at it is to consider $S_n$ as the collection of matrices with rows of the identity matrix permuted. Your map above simply then becomes the determinant map. The even permutations go to $1$ and the odd permutations go to $-1$.

Comment: (contd) My question is however is asking for a more general motivation of even/odd permutation for a fresh student. For example I used rotations in $D_n$ to motivate $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Likewise I was looking for a general motivation for even/odd permutations.

Comment: You can also look at $S_n$ as the Weyl group of the root system of $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$. Then the sign of $\sigma \in S_n$ is given by $(-1)^{l(\sigma)}$,  where $l(\sigma)$ is the length of $\sigma$ with respect to some base of the root system. But this is basically just the same thing as using the parity of the number of inversions

Comment: @Shahab I would recommend looking up the book "Adventures in Group Theory" by David Joyner. I mentioned the application to Rubik's cubes there, but, for example, Section 7.4 of the book proves that the 15 puzzle has no solution (this is, of course, fretty's answer), and the whole book is based around applying group theory to puzzles, and mostly these applications use symmetric group arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

My favourite application of even/odd permutations is in proving that the $15$ puzzle is impossible:

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m308-02b/projects/grant/fifteen.html

Essentially it boils down to the fact that any sequence of moves getting the empty space back to its original position must define an even permutation...but the puzzle starts off defining an odd permutation.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments one may use similar tactics to solve many "permutation puzzles", such as rubiks cube. Generally this is how most of the theory in $S_n$ is observed, through applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider orientation in Euclidean space to be intuitive, then the answer is affirmative: a permutation on $n$ symbols is even or odd according to whether it preserves or reverses orientation when acting on the standard basis of $n$-space.